# createTokenWithCard with tipsi-stripe does not return an error when expiration is incorrect?

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

Also posted in https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/issues/312

### Packages

```
"firebase": "^4.12.0",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.53.3",
"react-native-firebase": "^3.2.7",
"react-stripe-elements": "^1.6.0",
"tipsi-stripe": "^5.2.1"
```

### The problem

I am calling createTokenWithCard with an incorrect expiration date, and it doesn't seem to return an error, but returns a token.
Then, when I try to write this token into firebase, I see an error: "Your card was declined."
Does tipsi-stripe return an error and I don't check it properly?

### Here is the code:

```
addCard = async ({
    number, expMonth, expYear, cvc,
  }) => {
    this.setState({ addingCardInProcess: true });
    try {
      const tokenObject = await stripe.createTokenWithCard({
        number, expMonth, expYear, cvc
      });
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/stripe_customers/${uid()}/sources`)
        .push({ token: tokenObject.tokenId })
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ addingCardInProcess: false });
          this.cardAlert(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.setState({ addingCardInProcess: false });
          this.cardAlert(false, err.message);
        });
    } catch(err) {
      this.cardAlert(false, err.message);
      this.setState({ addingCardInProcess: false })
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say 'incorrect expiration date', do you mean a valid date(i.e. not in the past), but not the date that matches the card itself? Assuming that you do :

When you call `stripe.createTokenWithCard`, Stripe only checks that the values are valid in general terms, such as the card number passes the luhn check and the expiration date is in the future. There is no live validation made against the actual card when tokenizing. So the token can be created even if the expiration doesn't match the real card.

Later, when you attach the card to a customer(when you call your `/stripe_customers/${uid()}/sources` endpoint, I assume), Stripe will perform a $0/$1 authorization against the real card, and it is at this point you will get a decline if the expiry date was wrong — which is what you are seeing.

[0] - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

[1] - https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards#saving-credit-card-details-for-later

Comment: Wow, cool, thank you. If this id the case, shouldn't I get an error from firebase.push?

Comment: I'm not sure really, not massively familiar with firebase, only Stripe :) The error would be coming from here I think, if you are using it as a base. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js#L77

Comment: Thanks much. I will check. If I find anything I will post here.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @karllekko answer:

- So stripe doesn't check expiration and CVC, and returns a token even when they are incorrect
- Firebase, however, when it gets a stripe token to write, does the following:

  - Writes it
  - Validates it (including expiration and CVC)
  - If details are correct it replaces the token that it wrote before with card details (last 4 digits, brand, country, etc.)
  - If expiration or CVC are incorrect, it leaves the token in the database and adds an error message (with key='error'. "The card was declined" or another message if expiration is OK and CVC is incorrect).

So, if we want to know what is the real status of the card's validation, we need to wait until firebase replaces the initial token with the final details. This can take few seconds.

Just for testing purposes, this is the modified code that does this (the final code may check the status afterwards, or sleep a short period of time, then check the values in the database, etc., until the final values are set):

```
try {
      const tokenObject = await stripe.createTokenWithCard({
        number, expMonth, expYear, cvc
      });

      const id = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
      const body = { token: tokenObject.tokenId };
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/stripe_customers/${uid()}/sources`).child(id)
        .set(body)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("sleeping for a while");
          this.sleep(15000); // delay, waiting for firebase to update
          firebase
            .database()
            .ref(`/stripe_customers/${uid()}/sources/${id}`).once('value')
            .then((snapshot) => {

              const dataAfterValidation = snapshot.val();

              if (dataAfterValidation) {  // not null
                if (dataAfterValidation.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                  // card invalid
                  console.log("Card declined. Check expiration date and CVC.");
                } else if (dataAfterValidation.hasOwnProperty('brand')) {
                  console.log("Card added to the database.");
                } else {
                  // still not updated
                  console.log("Card is being validated.");
                }
              } else {
                console.log("Hmmm... Should not reach here...");
              }
            });

          this.setState({ addingCardInProcess: false });
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          this.setState({ addingCardInProcess: false });
          console.log("FAILURE", err.message);
        });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("FAILURE", err.message);
      this.setState({ addingCardInProcess: false })
    }
  };
```